# How to hide API key in Stripe Checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'am making Stripe payment in Reactjs project. Almost done with it except the API key which is to be hidden in environment variables.
See the below code

```
<StripeCheckout
       token = {onToken}
       stripeKey = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY
       billingAddress
       shippingAddress={false}
       amount={cartTotal * 100}
       closed={clearCart}
/>
```

I want to hide stripeKey as process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY and then set values in .env file, but, its not working. Any solution?

Comment: How it is not working, do you get a specific error?

Comment: @iTech When I set key its fine but, I want to hide the key as process.env.KEY.... then its not working

Comment: Do you use webpack to inject variables from .env? React code is client-side and environment variables are server-side

Comment: No I've not used webpack